# Waiting for cloud.typography to laod on localhost in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cloud.typography

Very often after a refresh (manual or on save, about 50% of the time) the page is stuck while loading the Gotham font we use from the cloud.typography servers. It only seems to happen locally, although this domain is also added in the cloud.typography settings.

I did not find anyone else having this issue and have no clue where else to look for a fix

I import the font.css as in the docs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.typography.com/{personal}/{personal}/css/fonts.css" />
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting in console or network tab

Comment: He Rikin, there is no error in the console and the network tab is still empty. The request to cloud.typography is pending and blocking everything else